# Positioning a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position the dropdown items in a menu, but it isn't working as expected. For example i want the dropdown items centered under the main items, see picture below
[image]

Here's the appropriate code

```
<nav>
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li id="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Recipes</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="meatballs.html">Meatballs</a></li>
              <li><a href="pancakes.html">Pancakes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

and here's the css, its kinda messy from experimenting rather much...

```
nav ul {
position:relative;
padding-left: 0;
margin:1px 0 30px 0;
background-color: #1d1d1d;
float: left;
width: 100%;

font-size:24px;
}
nav ul li { 
position:relative;
display: inline; 
}    
nav ul li a {
position:relative;
padding: 20px 20px;
background-color: #1d1d1d;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
float: left;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
background-color: #619f15;
color: #fff;
}
nav ul #active a {
background-color: #619f15;
color: #fff;
}

nav ul li ul {
position: absolute;
top:66px;
width: 50%;
font-size:12px;
display:none;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *centered*? the text of submenu items should be aligned with the text of parent, or the submenu item itself should be aligned with the parent item, or the text inside parent item..? the submenu items itself seems to have different dimensions so i's totally confusing.

Answer (score 1):

To get your dropdown items to behave properly you need to position them absolute, like you did, but it is much easier to position them from the top:

```
top: 100%;
left: 0;
```

That way, the dropdown items don't care about the height of your menu anymore and adjust their positioning according to the main menu.

As for the 'toggling', you can use:

```
nav ul li:hover >  ul {
    display: block;
}
```

So within your nav, as one hovers an `li` take the next `ul` and make it visible.

Complete example without additional styling:

```
nav ul {
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left: 0;
}
nav ul li:hover >  ul {
    display: block;
}
```

[**And heres a Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rL32n01p/)

Comment: Thanks, it kinda looks better now but im having another problem, Id' be really glad if you could help me with this. It looks like this right now, and im really confused why, http://imgur.com/WuMzIQw

Comment: Thanks c_k, it kinda looks better now but im having another problem, Id' be really glad if you could help me with this. It looks like this right now, and im really confused why, http://imgur.com/WuMzIQw
I've been trying to fix it, but changing my CSS too much screws up the whole layout of the website, also I fixed the dropdown menu instead with jquery.
If you could take a last look at my CSS i'd be really glad
http://pastebin.com/pbDKaEpW

Comment: Feel free to fork the fiddle with your updated code and I will see if I can help

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine, I fixed the issue by rewriting the css, thanks for the help